# How can I use an SVG sprite in an npm package?

Tags: reactjs, svg, node-modules, svg-sprite

My team is working on a React component library and we are using an SVG sprite for our icons. We have an `<Icon>` component that looks like this:

```
import Sprite from './sprite.svg';

const Icon = ({ icon }) => {
  return (
    <svg>
      <use href={`${Sprite}#${icon}`} />
    </svg>
  );
}
```

This works fine locally and we can see all of our icons. For example:

```
<Icon icon="person" />
```

We're using `parcel build` to build the library. When we build and use the node package in our application, however, the `href` URL points to `file:///sprite.cca210e1.svg#person` a local file, which cannot be read, so the `<svg>` is just blank.

What should the `href` URL be to allow us to use the sprite in our node package? Or is there a better way of going about this?